# Update db schema through custom test extension in Kotlin Spring Boot Hibernate JPA w/ Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a series of integration tests which need to run in parallel, so I'd like to create a custom test extension which generates a new (postgres) db schema for each test suite like this:

```
class PostgresDbIntegrationTestExtension : BeforeAllCallback{

  override fun beforeAll(extenstionContext: ExtensionContext?) {
    if (extenstionContext == null) {
      throw Exception("ExtensionContext is not initialized")
    }

    val applicationContext = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extenstionContext) as? AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
      ?: throw Exception("ApplicationContext is not initialized")

    val dbUrl = applicationContext.environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url")
    val dbUser = applicationContext.environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username")
    val dbPassword = applicationContext.environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password")
    val flywayMigrationFolder = applicationContext.environment.getProperty("spring.flyway.locations")
    val testSchemaName = getTestSchemaName(extenstionContext) // camel-case test class name
    val flyway = Flyway.configure()
      .dataSource(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword)
      .defaultSchema(testSchemaName)
      .schemas(testSchemaName)
      .locations(flywayMigrationFolder)
      .baselineOnMigrate(true)
      .load()

    flyway.migrate()

    // update the schema search path to the test schema
    System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", "$dbUrl&currentSchema=$testSchemaName")
```

Then I simply run my integration test with the `@ExtendsWith` annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = ["test", "test_db"])
@ExtendWith(PostgresDbIntegrationTestExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MySpecialRepositoryTest {
 ...
}
```

This doesn't work however. The db connection associated with the test still goes to the public schema, even though the url has been updated. I've tried several other approaches including:

1. Executing raw SQL in my `beforeAll()` method: `SET search_path to XXX`
2. Executing raw SQL in my `beforeEach()` method: `SET search_path to XXX`
3. Setting other properties like `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=$testSchemaName`
4. Directly set the schema on the connection:

```
val dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource::class.java)
val connection = dataSource.connection
connection.schema = testSchemaName
```

I think the problem here is that the DataSource bean is already initialized by the time I call `beforeAll` so the db connection never loads with the new config. I have no idea why explicitly setting the search_path doesn't work, but in my MySpecialRepositoryTest whenever I call jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SHOW search_path;", String::class.java) it only shows `public`.